# eureka status ip instead of Desktop or localhost

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I am working with Eureka Netflix and I have a little problem.
When the app register it self on eureka it register like DESKTOP....

[image]

And I want to be like http://IP:PORT

This is my server properties:

```
server.port=8761

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=OFF
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=OFF
```

And this is the client:

```
spring:
 application:
  name: Test 2
 server:
port: 0
eureka:
 client:
  serviceUrl:
   defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
```

So I think it is some configuration problem but I don't know what.

Comment: @YannicKlem  saw that post but it does not help me

Comment: @YannicKlem if you are talking about server properties then there eureka.instance.preferIpAddress is true

Comment: @YannicKlem i told you i have tried with eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164234/discussion-between-bambus-and-yannic-klem).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a better solution for me.
I changed the propertie file like this:

```
eureka config
eureka.name=eureka 
eureka.port=8761
eureka.preferSameZone=false
eureka.shouldUseDns=false
eureka.serviceUrl.default=http://localhost:8761/eureka/v2/
eureka.shouldOnDemandUpdateStatusChange=true
eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds=1
eureka.instance.leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds=2
# set application host
server.address=1.1.1.1
#set application port
server.port=8080
#set application name
spring.application.name=application


#configuration to set the ip of host instead of the default localhost
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.instance.ip-address=${server.address}
eureka.instance.instance-id=${server.address}:${server.port}
```

Now in the end it will show on eureka like

1.1.1.1:8080

Answer (score 5):

The text displayed in the status column is the instance-id.

With the following configuration in the client:

```
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.instance.instance-id=
```

you can force eureka dashboard to display the ip address in this column.

The property `eureka.instance.preferIpAddress`is just the address that is returned when you ask for the address of this instance. So if you don't set `eureka.instance.instance-id` to null, the instance-id still contains the hostname but the link you get to this instance is based on the ip instead of the host name.

Hope this helps